# Solve multiple equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have trouble using the Solve command in order to solve some equalities and inequalities. Here is a short example:

```
AA = {{a11, a12}, {a12, a22}};
Solve[Det[AA] > 0 && a11 == 2, {a11, a12, a22}]
```

This works and gives me the output that a11 has to be two and then an expression on a12 and a22. However now adding the matrix BB and using

```
BB = {{b11, b12}, {b12, b22}};
Solve[Det[AA] > 0 && a11 == 2 && Det[BB] > 0 & b11 == 1, {a11, a12, 
  a22, b11, b12, b22}]
```

Gives me some weird output I don't understand. Can someone please explain me what the problem with this syntax is or do I have to use a different command?

Best Regards

EDIT: The moment I post the question I find the mistake. I forgot an & symbol and overlooked this for like two days. Sorry

Comment: No problem. We all make errors. I mark this post as "mistake" so that it might be deleted.